# Finding intersection in a LinkedList - Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following fiddle below where I am attempting to find the intersection in two linked lists: 
https://jsfiddle.net/youngfreezy/cj54vtcx/

It works for lists that are the same size, however I can't figure out why it doesn't work for lists that are of different lengths.  I advance the pointer of the longer list (to account for a difference in length), yet when checking values something is going wrong.  This is an example of a linkedlist intersection:

[image]

My approach is as follows:

1. run through each list and calculate the length.
2. compare tails, if tails are different there is no intersection
3. set two pointers to start of the list --> I suspect this is my main problem
4. advance the pointer on the longer linkedlist by difference in length (helper function "advanceToKthNode" is relevant here) to ignore non relevant nodes.
5. traverse each list until the value at each pointer is the same.

This is my main function:

```
    LinkedList.prototype.isIntersection = function (LL1, LL2) {
  var tail1 = LL1.tail;
  var tail2 = LL2.tail;
  var length1 = LL1.getLength(LL1.head);
  var length2 = LL2.getLength(LL2.head);

  if (tail1.val !== tail2.val) {

    return false;
  }

  var shorter = ((length1 > length2) ? LL2 : LL1);

  var longer = ((length1 > length2) ? LL1 : LL2);

  var difference = Math.abs(length1 - length2);

  if (difference > 0) {

    //advance the longer one if there's a difference. this works.
    longer = this.advanceToKthNode(longer, difference);
    console.log(longer)

  }

  //point to the heads so you can iterate.
  var shortIterator = shorter.head;
  // this dosn't have a head if you advanced it.
  var longIterator = longer.head || longer.val;

  console.log(longIterator);
  // console.log(shortIterator);
  var intersection = "No Intersection";
  //don't count the tail as an intersection.
  while (longIterator && shortIterator && (longIterator !== longer.tail)) {
    console.log("LONG", longIterator)
    console.log("SHORT", shortIterator)
    if (longIterator.val === shortIterator.val) {
      intersection = longIterator.val;
    }
    shortIterator = shortIterator.next;
    longIterator = longIterator.next;
  }

  // while ((longIterator && shortIterator)&&longIterator.val !== shortIterator.val) {
  //   // console.log(longIterator);
  //   shortIterator = shortIterator.next;
  //   longIterator = longIterator.next;
  // }

  return intersection;
};
```

Comment: So the linked lists you are trying to compare have the structure of a tree and at some point they will be the same?

Comment: Didn't think about it that way! I am trying to practice LinkedList problems through learning how to do this

Comment: What do you mean exactly by intersection? That's what I was trying to ask, the picture shows a scenario where you have to find the node where they join and the rest will be the same. This would mean you could reverse the two lists and just compare nodes until they are not the same any more.

Comment: Basically the point at which two linked lists "overlap" at one specific node. the tails will always be the same, but not necessarily everything between the intersection and the tail.